# How to preload shared library and wrap malloc alongside using functions which use malloc in the same wrapped function?

Tags: c, linker, mocking, malloc, shared-libraries

I want to wrap `malloc` in a function which would print the allocation size, pointer address and the time of the allocation. This can be achieved preloading my shared library with my implementation of `malloc`. This code achieves that:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;
static void* (*real_calloc)(size_t nelements, size_t elementSize) = NULL;

static void init(void)
{
    real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    if (NULL == real_malloc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
    }
}

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if(real_malloc == NULL)
    {
        init();
    }

    void *p = NULL;

    p = real_malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "size=%lu, pointer=%p\n", size, p);
    return p;
}
```

However if I add the time printing function to `malloc`:

```
static void printTime()
{
  time_t timer;
    char buffer[26];
    struct tm* tm_info;

    time(&timer);
    tm_info = localtime(&timer);

    strftime(buffer, 26, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm_info);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buffer);
}
```

and add `time.h` header and run my .so library with the executable it will simply freeze and do nothing.

I suspect that `time` or `localtime` call `malloc` under the hood and somehow this causes problems. On the other hand `real_malloc` is indeed called so there shouldn't be a problem.

My executable is multi-threaded but adding mutexes didn't help. The way I compile the .so is as follows:

`gcc -fPIC -shared  -o bin/libpreload.so myAlloc.c -ldl`

The issue can verified using Linux `ps` program:

`cd /bin && LD_PRELOAD=/home/username/Desktop/alloc/bin/libpreload.so ./ps`

Also below is the `ldd` output for my .so:
[image]

Comment: Your printTime is incorrect

Comment: also the vdso has peculiarities when it comes to querying the clock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your logging functions in `malloc` ends up calling `malloc` you need to break out of the recursive loop.

So only do logging when malloc is called outside of your logging.

```
void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if(real_malloc == NULL)
    {
        init();
    }

    void *p = NULL;

    p = real_malloc(size);

    if (do_logging)
      {
         do_logging = 0;
         fprintf(stderr, "size=%lu, pointer=%p\n", size, p);
         printTime();
         do_logging = 1;
      }
    return p;
}
```

Naturally if you want this to work in a multithreaded program you have to put `do_logging` in thread-local storage. In c11 and later you can do it like this:

```
#include <threads.h>
thread_local int do_logging = 1;
```

Oh, and your `init`-function may not be thread safe.

Comment: I need to use to protect `do_logging` because my executable is multi-threaded right? Because my shared library is not, it just declares `malloc`.

Comment: If `malloc` may be called from multiple threads at the same time, it has to be multithread-safe. It has nothing to do with which library starts the threads, but only on how the library functions are called